# Firebase DynamicLinks not open after clicked <goo.gl button

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have problem with firebase dynamicLinks :

the scenario that I check :

1)I press firebase deeplink from nots and the app open, in the top left of
   scree <- goo.gl and the right nots ->.

2) press the nots> button move to nots app.

3) try again the link open the app again , but now I press the

4)press in nots link not open the app and open safari with "open link in 'my app' " press open and the app store open.

to fix this I need to long press in the link and choose "open in 'my app'"
but after I return step 3 the link not open again in app.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen what I can do with this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how Universal links behave on iOS itself, and you found the solution that you posted:

> to fix this I need to long press in the link and choose "open in 'my app'"

I just tested this locally, and it behaved as expected.